# c# structural comparison of hashsets of int arrays

Tags: c#, collections

```
var comparer = ...
var s1 = new HashSet<int[]>(new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } }, comparer);
var s2 = new HashSet<int[]>(new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } }, comparer);
```

Is there a (default?) comparer I can plug into HashSet so that s1.Equals(s2) is true?
I know there is a StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer, but HashSet requires a generic IEqualityComparer<>.

**UPDATE:**

Doesn't look like it could ever work. The closest I get is to use HashSet.SetEquals and plug in a wrapper for StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer as suggested by phoog

```
    internal class GenericStructuralComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        static GenericStructuralComparer<T> _instance;

        public static IEqualityComparer<T> Instance
        {
            get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new GenericStructuralComparer<T>()); }
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
        }
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<T> StructuralComparer<T>()
    {
        return GenericStructuralComparer<T>.Instance;
    }
```

And then

```
var comparer = StructuralComparer<int[]>();
var s1 = new HashSet<int[]>(new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } }, comparer);
var s2 = new HashSet<int[]>(new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } }, comparer);
s1.SetEquals(s2); // True
```

Comment: I don't know of a built in one, but it's relatively easy to implement one. The biggest issue I see is that `GetHashCode()` will be `O(n)`.

Comment: Would `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` do the job for you?  Not sure if there would be ordering problems or not...possibly..

Comment: You could implement `IEqualityComparer<int[]>` on a wrapper class that delegates to `StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos `GetHashCode` is almost always O(n) (unless it's precomputed or not implemented by value)

Answer (score 3):

No - because implicit array equality is not defined beyond reference quality; and at runtime an array won't provide a `GetHashCode` that will take into account the inner elements - because, correctly, there's no general case for combining hashcodes - so the framework doesn't try to implement one.

You'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

No, Default there is no comparer but you can create an extention method like this which does the trick:

```
public static class HashSetExt
{
    public static bool HashSetEqualsTo<T>(this HashSet<T> set, HashSet<T> other)
    {
        return //Your own compare method
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s1 = new HashSet<int[]>(new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } });
        var s2 = new HashSet<int[]>(new[] { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } });
        var isEquals = s1.HashSetEqualsTo<int[]>(s2);
    }
}
```