# HashSet of int[]

Tags: c#

I'm doing some programming exercises with C# to learn how to solve them on an interview.

There is one condition: `(1, 1, 1, 2)` is equal to `(1, 1, 2, 1)`. I think I could check this condition with this [StackOverflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1673388/68571).

The problem is that I will have many quadruples to check, so I have thought to use a HashSet of arrays (`int[]`) to store it, but I don't know if HashSet will work with arrays.

Another option is to have a list of lists, and every time I'm going to add a new quadruple, loop all of the lists and check if already exists.

What do you think?

By the way, I'm trying to solve this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/xor-quadruples/problem

Comment: Question: if (1,1,2,1) is equal to (1,1,1,2): is it ever actually necessary to have (1,1,2,1) existing? Meaning: if you normalized order during the constructor: everything after becomes trivial and efficient, including equality and hashcode. Side note: you'd probably want a readonly struct for the actual type representation.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm trying to solve this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/xor-quadruples/problem

Comment: In that case, I think you're going about this in a very wrong way; see my answer for more context

Comment: @Servy Not sure that's a great duplicate, there are efficiencies to be had here over the generalized solution due to duplicates (so just need to maintain a count)

Comment: @Charlieface A problem that they've already stated in the question they know how to solve, they just don't know how to scale it up, which the duplicate shows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. But, (1) if you are saying the Hashset is to compare the elements of two quadruples, it won't work as you intend.

> The HashSet class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains **no duplicate elements**, and whose elements are in no particular order.

> A HashSet collection is not sorted and **cannot contain duplicate elements**. If order or element duplication is more important than performance for your application, consider using the List class together with the Sort method.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-collections-generic-hashset%7Bt%7D

(2) If you are talking about a HashSet of arrays or a HashSet of Lists, it won't work as it is since arrays or lists are reference types.

See this question about how arrays/lists in HashSet are compared and how they can be customized.
[HashSet usable types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193952/hashset-usable-types)
[c# structural comparison of hashsets of int arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911236/c-sharp-structural-comparison-of-hashsets-of-int-arrays)
[How does HashSet compare elements for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality)

To use a HashSet of arrays, you can customize the equality interface of HashSet by implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>`, but it will require some additional work.

(3) I think you may use some collection of lists/arrays (a list of lists, an arraylist of lists, or an arraylist of arrays), where the inner lists are always sorted so that the comparisons work as you intend.

(4) If you assume only quadruples as inputs, you may use a `HashSet` of `Tuple`s. Tuples already have their own equality definition. However, you should consider that two tuples with the same elements but in different order are not equal. You may sort the elements of Tuples.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to solve this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/xor-quadruples/problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use some collection of lists, where the inner lists are always sorted so that the comparisons work as you are intending.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `Dictionary<int, int>` where the key is the number to be stored and the value is the number of times.

```cs
Dictionary<int, int> ToDictionaryOfInts(int[] values)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    foreach (var v in values)
        dict[v] = dict.TryGetValue(v, out var count) ? count + 1 : 1;
// slightly more efficient in newer versions of .NET:
//      (ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dict, v, out _)) += 1;
}
```

To compare them you could create a custom `IEqualityComparer`

```cs
class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<TKey, TValue>
    where TKey : notnull
{
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<TKey, TValue>? a, Dictionary<TKey, TValue>? b)
    {
        if (a == null && b == null)
            return true;

        if (a?.Count != b?.Count)
            return false;

        foreach (var kvp in a)
        {
            if (!b.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out var val) || val != kvp.Value)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<TKey, TValue>? dict)
    {
        if (dict == null)
            return 0;

        var hashcode = new HashCode();
        foreach (var kvp in a)
        {
            hashcode.Add(kvp.Key);
            hashcode.Add(kvp.Value);
        }
        return hashcode.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then:

```cs
var areEqual = comparer.Equals(firstDict, secondDict);
```